# Change of variables during differentiation

Tags: derivatives, quantum-mechanics, change-of-variable

If we have a function: $\psi(x)$ and $x=\rho\gamma$ where $\rho$ is a constant

Then is the following statement correct:

$1)~~$ $\psi(x) =\psi(\rho \gamma)=\rho \psi(\rho)$

What is the equation for : $\frac{d\psi(\gamma)}{d\gamma}$ and $\frac{d^2\psi(\gamma)}{d\gamma^2}$

Below is my attempt at finding it:

[image]

---

This question is the context of findings the solution of simple harmonic oscillator

[image]

I am having trouble understanding how $9.19$ is derived from $9.18$ .

Comment: Typos? How are 1,2 related to 1)2)3)?

Comment: $\psi(\rho\gamma)=\rho\psi(\gamma)$ iff $\psi$ is of the form $\psi=cx$.

Comment: is $\psi(\rho y) = \rho\psi(y) $ true for wavefunctions?

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:**  I am having trouble understanding how $9.19$ is derived from $9.18$ .

**Answer:** There are some mistakes (may be printing mistake) in their  calculation. You can see those in my answer which I have already fixed (in red color). Here we go:

$$-\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m}\dfrac{d^2\psi(x)}{dx^2}+\dfrac{mw^2x^2}{2}\psi(x)=E~\psi(x)\tag{9.18}$$Putting $~x=\rho\gamma\implies \psi(x) =\psi(\rho \gamma)=\rho \psi(\color{red}\gamma)~$ and the partial derivatives became $$\dfrac{d\psi(x)}{dx}=\dfrac{d\psi(\rho\gamma)}{d\gamma}\cdot\dfrac{d\gamma}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{\rho}\cdot\rho\dfrac{d\psi(\gamma)}{d\gamma}=\dfrac{d\psi(\gamma)}{d\gamma}~~~~~~~~\text{and}$$
$$\frac{d^2\psi(x)}{dx^2}=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{d\psi(x)}{dx}\right)=\dfrac{d}{d\gamma}\left(\dfrac{d\psi(\gamma)}{d\gamma}\right)\cdot\dfrac{d\gamma}{dx}=\frac{d^2\psi(\gamma)}{d\gamma^2}\cdot\dfrac{d\gamma}{dx}=\color{red}{\dfrac 1\rho}\cdot\frac{d^2\psi(\gamma)}{d\gamma^2}~.$$

Now putting the above values in equation $(9.18)$ we have,
$$-\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m}\dfrac 1\rho\dfrac{d^2\psi(\gamma)}{d\gamma^2}+\dfrac{mw^2\rho^2 \gamma^2}{2}\rho\psi(\gamma)=E~\rho\psi(\gamma)$$
$$\implies \dfrac{d^2\psi(\gamma)}{d\gamma^2}-\dfrac{2m\rho}{\hbar^2}\dfrac{mw^2\rho^2 \gamma^2}{2}\rho\psi(\gamma)=-\dfrac{2m\rho}{\hbar^2}E~\rho\psi(\gamma)$$
$$\implies \dfrac{d^2\psi(\gamma)}{d\gamma^2}-\dfrac{ m^2w^2\rho^4}{\hbar^2}\gamma^2\psi(\gamma)=-\dfrac{2mE\rho^2}{\hbar^2}\psi(\gamma)\tag{9.19}$$